# Error when downloading library from github

Tags: r, github-api, devtools

I encountered error when I try to instal a github library to R as follows:

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("swager/balanceHD")
```

However, the following error message is displayed:

```
Downloading github repo swager/balanceHD@master
Error: 'new_handle' is not an exported object from 'namespace:curl'
```

Any idea on why this happens?

PS: Here's the output of devtools::session_info():

```
Session info ---------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
 system   x86_64, darwin10.8.0        
 ui       RStudio (0.98.953)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz                                   

Packages -------------------------------------------------------------------
 package    * version    date       source                      
 curl       * 0.5        2015-02-01 CRAN (R 3.0.2)              
 data.table   1.9.2      2014-02-27 CRAN (R 3.0.2)              
 devtools     1.7.0      2015-01-17 CRAN (R 3.0.2)              
 httr       * 1.0.0.9000 2015-06-29 Github (hadley/httr@d9395f2)
 MASS         7.3-37     2015-01-10 CRAN (R 3.0.2)              
 plyr         1.8.1      2014-02-26 CRAN (R 3.0.2)              
 R6         * 1.0.1      2014-07-17 CRAN (R 3.0.2)              
 Rcpp       * 0.11.5     2015-03-06 CRAN (R 3.0.2)              
 reshape2   * 1.4.1      2014-12-06 CRAN (R 3.0.2)              
 rstudio    * 0.98.953   2014-07-09 local                       
 rstudioapi * 0.2        2014-12-31 CRAN (R 3.0.2)              
 stringr    * 0.6.2      2012-12-06 CRAN (R 3.0.0)
```

Comment: did you mean `install_github`? And can you post the output of `devtools::session_info()`?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the catch.  I've include output of devtools::session_info()

Comment: Looking at your session info, your R version *3.0.2 (2013-09-25)* is going on three years old, perhaps you could update R? At the very least, you could update the `curl` package as that seems to be causing the immediate issue. You have curl version 0.5, the current version is 0.9.7.

Comment: Though R 3.3.0 is scheduled for release next week, so you could wait until then...

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think you should update `R`. `3.0.2` is considered ancient. No doubt it was a great piece of software back then and in a way still is, but 3 years is a ton of time given the pace at which the language and its entire environment has been evolving.

If everything is up-to-date, communication between R and other programs such as `curl` is much easier. Plus bugs are easier to track down, because most of the people here cannot reproduce your problem easily. Most people have much newer installations of R and also the entire ecosystem is much newer.